# Getting file not found error with pdebuild

Tags: debian, build-server, deb

I am attempting to build a Debian package using `pdebuild` on my main development server (running Debian wheezy). Here is the command I run:

```
pdebuild --pbuilder cowbuilder --buildresult .. \
         --debbuildopts -i -- \
         --basepath /var/cache/pbuilder/base-wheezy.cow \
         --distribution wheezy --configfile /etc/pbuilder/wheezy
```

This works on other servers, but on one server I get this output:

```
I: using cowbuilder as pbuilder
dpkg-buildpackage: source package libexample-orange-util-perl
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.08
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by John User <jonuser@example.com>
 dpkg-source -i --before-build libexample-orange-util-perl
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -i -b libexample-orange-util-perl
dpkg-source: info: using source format `3.0 (native)'
dpkg-source: info: building libexample-orange-util-perl in libexample-orange-util-perl_0.08.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building libexample-orange-util-perl in libexample-orange-util-perl_0.08.dsc
 dpkg-genchanges -S >../libexample-orange-util-perl_0.08_source.changes
dpkg-genchanges: including full source code in upload
 dpkg-source -i --after-build libexample-orange-util-perl
dpkg-buildpackage: source only upload: Debian-native package
File not found: ../libexample-orange-util-perl_0.08.dsc
```

There is no file `../libexample-orange-util-perl_0.08.dsc`, but on other build servers no such file is needed (it gets created by the package build).

What is causing this "file not found" error?

Answer (score 0):

I never use pdbuild but i think is a path error because your libexample-orange-util-perl_0.08.dsc is generated.

Probably, this link can help you: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-sourcebuild

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my problem was that I was attempting to build in an AFS directory. I resolved the issue by using a different pam module for sudo:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# /etc/pam.d/sudo

@include common-auth
@include common-account

# @include common-session-noninteractive
#
# Instead of including the stock common-session-noninteractive we
# use parts of it, overriding minimum_uid for pam_afs_session
# so that sudo will be able to get AFS tokens (helps with cowbuilder)
session optional                pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
session required                pam_unix.so
session optional                pam_afs_session.so minimum_uid=0
```